`osEligibility.status reasons is empty` MacOS 15 beta
After upgrading my dev environment from:
iPhone 15 Pro iOS 17+
M2 MBP MacOS 14+
Xcode 15+

to
iPhone 15 Pro iOS 18 beta 3 (22A5307f)
M2 MBP MacOS 15 beta (24A5279h)
Xcode 16 beta (16A5171c)

My iOS app started lagging. Right after the lag I would see multiple lines of the following error printed:
osEligibility.status reasons is empty

Additionally, this lag seems to only be there when my phone is running the app triggered from Xcode. That is, if I unplug the USB-C to disconnect my phone from the laptop, it disappears.
I searched everywhere and this seems to be the only post that mentions similar issues.
Anyone knows what this is?
